# MySQL insert operation hang while another update operation is running, but can't figure out why

Tags: mysql, blocking

Transaction 1:

```
begin;
update t_info set gender=1 where c_score > 85;
```

Transaction 2:

```
begin;
insert into t_info(c_id,c_class_no,c_score,c_name,gender) values (4,99,50,'gap',1);
```

Transaction 2 hangs, and I can't figure out why.

Preconditions: mysql `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19-17` tx_isolation: `REPEATABLE-READ`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t_info`;
CREATE TABLE `t_info` (
  `c_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'primary key',
  `c_class_no` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `c_score` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 male, 1 female',
  PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`),
  KEY `idx_name_score` (`c_name`,`c_score`),
  KEY `idx_score` (`c_score`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `t_info` 
VALUES 
(1,1,60,'no1',0),
(2,2,60,'no2',0),
(3,3,60,'no3',0),
(6,4,78,'gap',1),
(7,5,95,'no5',0),
(10,8,87,'jianhaiqing',0),
(11,36,20,'no20',0),
(14,13,100,'no13',0),
(20,21,120,'no21',0),
(21,24,83,'no87-2',0);
```

[image: table recods]

Comment: When you have an actively blocked trx, run ‘SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G’ and review the transactions section.

Comment: It's an exactly right direction to figure out the problem;

Comment: ---TRANSACTION 11465908, ACTIVE 3 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 51589, OS thread handle 139964999091968, query id 157268 172.18.70.57 root update
insert into t_info(c_id,c_class_no,c_score,c_name,gender) values (4,99,50,'gap',1)
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 3 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 5547 page no 3 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `lock_spy`.`t_info` trx id 11465908 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
------------------

Comment: Isn't this a pretty straightforward table lock during the update? Presuming you don't have an index on the predicate column, it will have to do a table scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
---TRANSACTION 11465908, ACTIVE 3 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 51589, OS thread handle 139964999091968, query id 157268 172.18.70.57 root update
insert into t_info(c_id,c_class_no,c_score,c_name,gender) values (4,99,50,'gap',1)
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 3 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 5547 page no 3 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `lock_spy`.`t_info` trx id 11465908 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
------------------
```

Transaction 1: would lock the whole table because of  MySQL optimization itself since the table rows is very small.

One thing: if the table rows is large enough, eg. more than 1000, or others. MySQL would use the idx_score index to scan c_score>85;

Another:
Using  force index(idx_score) to query the data. Then, MySQL only lock secondary index idx_score ( also gaps), and corresponding records( not record gap).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this a pretty straightforward table lock during the update. Presuming you don't have an index on the predicate column, it will have to do a table scan to evaluate the `> 85`.

Adding an index on `c_score` should remedy this by allowing for a seek (or at least an index scan) to occur.

Comment: i have figure out the issue. Use the "update t_info force index(idx_score) set gender=1 where c_score > 85 ;" instead. The insert operation can be committed successfully. Using  force index(idx_score) to  disallow MySQL optimization due the minor rows.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. If the force usage of the index stopped the locking, then you're on the right track. I wonder if your statistics are off? Try removing the `force` and running `ANALYZE TABLE t_info;` to rebuild the indexes and refresh the stats. Barring that, I'd reckon that the distribution of rows `> 85` is so skewed that it's electing a table scan anyways because it's more efficient.

Comment: I did `ANALYZE TABLE t_info`, explain tools still use `Key PRIMARY` instead of `idx_score `since there are only `10` records in this table. So table scan may be more efficient. Only the `optimization algorithm` can tell the truth and why.

Comment: @pimbrouwers - 40% of the table is `>85`, so the Optimizer is very likely to ignore the index and do a table scan since it is deemed faster.  Change to `>111` and it will probably automatically use the index.

Comment: @RickJames seems that way. The picture wasn't posted when I originally provided my answer. I will edit.